# Excel VBA: Paste Excel Range as a Table in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm trying to automate the creation of powerpoint decks that i have to produce every month.  I'm working in Excel VBA and cant figure out how to copy a range from excel, and paste it into a slide as a table.

Below is the code i have so far:

```
Sub Open_PowerPoint_Presentation()

Dim objPPT As Object, _
PPTPrez As PowerPoint.Presentation, _
pSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
objPPT.Visible = True

Set PPTPrez = objPPT.Presentations.Open("file location")

Set pSlide = PPTPrez.Slides(4)

Dim RevenueDetail As Range
Dim RevenueDetailTable As Object

Sheets("Revenue By Type Slide").Activate

Set RevenueDetail = Range("B4:I18")
RevenueDetail.Copy

Set RevenueDetailTable = pSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)

With RevenueDetailTable

.Left = 43.99961
.Top = 88.61086
.Width = 471.2827
.Height = 395.2163

End With

End Sub
```

This works OK but it pastes the excel range as a picture which is not ideal.  i'd like to paste it as a table which is what the default paste option does, but then i lose the ability to re-size and re-position it on the slide by the means that i'm currently using.  I've been messing with this for awhile and can't seem to get it right.

if i modify

```
Set RevenueDetailTable = pSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)
```

and change it to

```
Set RevenueDetailTable = pSlide.Shapes.Paste
```

it pastes in the format i want but i cant figure out how to reposition and resize.  any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Following [this](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/3/17/copy-paste-an-excel-range-into-powerpoint-with-vba) website, I get exactly what you want when I change `mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2` into `mySlide.Shapes.Paste`. When you now fidle around with `.Top`, `.Left` and `.Width` you'll get what you need. Good luck with the implementation :)

Comment: @JvdV thats what i've tried already.  when i change PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile) to just Paste, it pastes as a table.  however, i cant figure out how to reposition and resize.  using a With statement with the ".Top = 88", etc no longer works.

Comment: I've tried your code after some small changes to make it run with an example PowerPoint presentation (and leaving out the worksheet activation) and came to the conclusion I've put into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it... just needed to add a line "pSlide.Select" to select the slide i'm pasting into prior to pasting, and change .PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile) to just .Paste...thanks for all help!!!!

```
Sub Open_PowerPoint_Presentation()

Dim objPPT As Object, _
PPTPrez As PowerPoint.Presentation, _
pSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Dim RevenueDetail As Range
Dim RevenueDetailTable As Object

Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
objPPT.Visible = True

Set PPTPrez = objPPT.Presentations.Open("file location")

Set pSlide = PPTPrez.Slides(4)

Set RevenueDetail = Sheets("Revenue By Type Slide").Range("B4:I18")
RevenueDetail.Copy

pSlide.Select 'needed to add this line
Set RevenueDetailTable = pSlide.Shapes.Paste

With RevenueDetailTable

.Left = 43.99961
.Top = 88.61086
.Width = 471.2827
.Height = 395.2163

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This shouldn't be needed as you have `Set pSlide = PPTPrez.Slides(4)`. However, if this works for you, then that's all that matters :). Happy days.

Comment: @JvdV thats what i was thinking so i never considered adding it.  very strange but its working now thank goodness... ive been scratching my head at this for hours sadly...

Comment: @ Sometimes it's in the details :). However, I still think it shouldn't be necessary. Copied over your code, small additions to make it run locally and it did exactly what you wanted without selecting a slide. I've Always learned to stay away from `.Select`.