# How can extract data while keeping format from excel to PowerPoint using vba

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

i have code that can extract data only but i want to extract with their format

can u plz help me with this issue?

this is my code so far:
'''

```
Dim PPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation 
Dim PPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide 
Dim ExcRng As Range
Dim RngArray As Variant 
Set PPTApp = New PowerPoint.Application 
PPTApp.Visible = True 
Set PPTPres = PPTApp.Presentations.Add 
RngArray = Array(Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D4:E8"))
For x = LBound(RngArray) To UBound(RngArray) 
Set ExcRng = RngArray(x) ExcRng.Copy 
Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slides.Add(x + 1, ppLayoutBlank) 
PPTSlide.Shapes.Paste Next x 
End Sub
```

'''

Comment: There is a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51827899/excel-vba-paste-excel-range-as-a-table-in-powerpoint) which might help you

Answer (score 0):

Try

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ppt()

    Dim PPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim PPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim ExcRng As Range, RngArray As Variant, i As Long

    Set PPTApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    PPTApp.Visible = True
    Set PPTPres = PPTApp.Presentations.Add
    RngArray = Array(Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D4:E8"))
    For i = LBound(RngArray) To UBound(RngArray)
        Set ExcRng = RngArray(i)
        ExcRng.Copy
        Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slides.Add(i + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
        With PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteOLEObject)
            .Left = 300
            .Top = 100
        End With
    Next 
End Sub
```